# sample SSL code server

Tags: xcode, ipad, ssl, openssl

I need a little server (OBJ-C, iPad, XCode) using ssl negociations and exchanges when a client tries to connect.

Is someone knows how to do this or have a little example?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

[cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/)